# Check polygon intersection in R: sf::intersects incorrectly returns TRUE result while rgeos::gIntersects correctly returns FALSE

Tags: r, intersection, projection, r-sf, rgeo-shapefile

I'm trying to check whether two polygons intersect in R. When plotting, they clearly do not. When checking the intersection, `rgeos::gIntersects()` currently returns `FALSE`, while `sf::intersects()` returns `TRUE`. I imagine this is due to the polygons being (1) large and (2) close together, so something about when on a flat surface they don't appear to intersect but on a sphere they would appear to intersect?

Ideally I could keep my workflow all in `sf` -- but I'm wondering if there's a way to use `sf::intersects()` (or another `sf` function) that will return `FALSE` here?

Here's an example:

```
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

#### Make Polygons
poly_1 <- c(xmin = -124.75961, ymin = 49.53330, xmax = -113.77328, ymax = 56.15249) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()
st_crs(poly_1) <- 4326

poly_2 <- c(xmin = -124.73214, ymin = 25.11625, xmax = -66.94889, ymax = 49.38330) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()
st_crs(poly_2) <- 4326

#### Plotting
# Visually, the polygons do not intersect
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = poly_1) %>%
  addPolygons(data = poly_2)

#### Check Intersection
# returns FALSE
gIntersects(poly_1 %>% as("Spatial"), 
            poly_2 %>% as("Spatial"))

# returns TRUE
st_intersects(poly_1,
              poly_2,
              sparse = F)
```

Here's the polygons, which visually do not intersect.
[image: Polygons]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, with the root cause being difference between planar (on a flat surface) and spherical (on a globe) geometry.

On a plane - which is a simplified approach that GEOS takes - the four corners  of a polygon are connected by four straight lines, the sum of angles is 360° degrees etc. Geometry works as Euclid taught ages ago.

But, and this is crucial, this is not how the world works. On a globe the four connections of polygon are not straight lines but great circles. Or rather they are straight when drawn on a globe, and curved when rolled flat one a planar surface (such as a map or your computer screen).

Because an example is more than a 1000 words consider this piece of code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# make polygons
poly_1 <- c(xmin = -124.75961, ymin = 49.53330, xmax = -113.77328, ymax = 56.15249) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()
st_crs(poly_1) <- 4326

poly_2 <- c(xmin = -124.73214, ymin = 25.11625, xmax = -66.94889, ymax = 49.38330) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()
st_crs(poly_2) <- 4326

# this is what you *think* you see (and what GEOS sees, being planar) 
# = four corners connected by straight lines
# & no intersecton
mapview::mapview(list(poly_1, poly_2))
```

[image]

```
# this is what you *should* see (and what {s2} sees, being spherical)
# = four corners connected by great circles
# & an obvious intersection around the lower right corner of the small polygon
poly_1alt <- st_segmentize(poly_1, units::set_units(1, degree))
poly_2alt <- st_segmentize(poly_2, units::set_units(1, degree))

mapview::mapview(list(poly_1alt, poly_2alt))
```

[image]

You have two options:

- accept that your thinking about polygons was wrong, and embrace spherical, i.e. `{s2}` logic.

This should be in theory the correct approach, but somewhat counter intuitive.

- make `{sf}` abandon spherical approach to polygons, and force it to apply planar approach (such as GEOS uses).

This would be in theory a wrong approach, but consistent both with your planar intuition and previous behaviour of most GIS tools, including `{sf}` prior to  version 1.0.0

```
# remedy (of a kind...) = force planar geometry operations

sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)

st_intersects(poly_1, poly_2, sparse = F)
#      [,1]
# [1,] FALSE
```

Comment: I'd take issue with your idea that one is "correct" here. Correctness only makes sense within some greater framework and if your framework is that lat-long is a cartesian coordinate system then the great circles are wrong. I'm sure there are regulatory standards where this is true (think of borders being defined along lines of latitude, for example).

Comment: @Spacedman I definitely agree that "correctness" is a slippery term. In general we tend to think of Earth as a sphere, and laugh at the flat earthers - but this has consequences of non-Euclidean geometry that we often find difficult to work with. Even our tools are not quite consistent - like how come that segmentizing a polygon changes its shape? The points should lie on the original line from the very beginning.

Comment: This is really surprising to me, in the other direction. My "intuition" is that making a polygon with a bbox that way should result in great circles already. What is the "right" way to say, I want to fill in a "box" that curves along a particular latitude line?